# knockout.js: how to handle dynamically nested arrays from json

Tags: arrays, json, dynamic, knockout.js, nested

Sorry for the obvious question for someone...

The problem: i'm trying to make a sort of file manager that can handle files and folders, like a filesystem, retrieving data from a JSON.

the user can add as folders as he wants so i could have foldC inside foldB inside foldC, i cannot know how many folders are nested.

in my mind, in the html page i will display only the root folder at the beginning; when the user click on a folder i want to "enter" in the folder, showing the content of the folder (with a back button) and hiding other content of the root folder (like microsoft windows explorer). and you can iterate this process with subfolders.

I think i need a sort of code that dynamically add html code...but i really don't know where to start using knockout.js for doing this...

can you point me somewhere? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite hard to answer his question without more details but the starting point should be the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html). As you drill-down in you arrays, you control the creation of the objects with "create" (check the "Customizing object construction using “create” section).